# Shortcuts to calculating minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

What are some basic shortcuts and tricks to calculating minimal polynomials with knowledge of the characteristic polynomial?

In a specific setting, suppose we're working with
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -4 & 4\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The characteristic polynomial is $(t-1)^3(t-2)$ and I'm hoping there's something better than trial and error to which value of $i$ gives the right answer among $ \left\{  (t-1)^i(t-2) \right\}_{1\leq i \leq 3}$...

Comment: Is Jordan decomposition counted as `better`? It directly determines the exponents, but is not trivial to compute, nor does it follow from the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @awllower I don't understand the question, but I never said it follows from the characteristic polynomial. I'm just saying that given the characteristic polynomial you can always find the minimal polynomial by trial and error, and I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: I see. Then I am afraid Jordan decomposition is not seen directly once given characteristic polynomial: some calculations are still in need.

Comment: @awllower I never asked for Jordan decomposition, only for the minimal polynomial. You're saying there's no observation here to save work?

Comment: I mean I don't have observation here.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, we have

$$ A - I = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & -4 & 4\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

so $\dim \ker(A - I) = 2$. Thus, the Jordan form of $A - I$ must be

$$ \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

and the corresponding minimal polynomial is $(t-1)^2(t-3)$.

Comment: Note: $\dim \ker(A - \lambda I)$ is always the total number of Jordan blocks associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ (since each Jordan block corresponds to some eigenvector).  Moreover, the degree of $(t - \lambda)$ in the minimal polynomial is the size of the *largest* Jordan block associated with $\lambda$.